# radiobutton color change in transparent background activty

Tags: android

I ve created a transparent background Activity ,and used this code

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#31f7f4f4</item> 
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>

</style>
```

its working fine but my problem is that i have radio button in this activity ,its color is coloraccent but coloraccent is inverted (color change from pink(coloraccent) to green ),can anyone tell me how to solve it?
tnx in advanced

Comment: simple bro, define another color same as coloraccent and use as a background.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya u re right , tanx alot :)))